# command prompt is not exiting after executing the bat file (java program) in scheduled mode

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

The following code in a batch file will exit properly if I execute it manually. However, if I run the batch file using a scheduler app, it is not terminating on Windows Server 2008 machine. Application is exiting however cmd is not.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar myAPP.jar -o true
EXIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is using `EXIT;` instead of just `exit`.

Although on reaching end of batch file the command process automatically terminates and therefore `exit` at end of a batch file is usually not needed. The exception is the batch file is called from another batch file and under certain conditions the entire command process executing both batch files should be exited immediately without returning back to parent batch file.

The command **EXIT** without parameter `/B` always results in exiting command process making it also very difficult to debug a batch file from within a command prompt window as just `exit` results in closing also the command prompt window. So in general it is always better to using `exit /B` when needed at all.

But most likely `java.exe` does not exit and therefore the batch processing does not end.

There are several information missing in question.

1. Why using a batch file at all when running only `java.exe` with several parameters?
   Why not creating a scheduled task with that command line?
2. What is the environment for `java.exe` on running this command line as scheduled task?
   Is the scheduled task configured to run with system account or with your user account?
   The environment variables defined for system account are surely different to the environment variables of your user account. Java usually depends on several environment variables, except the data predefined with environment variables are specified on command line with using the appropriate [Java command line options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).
3. Why not using `javaw.exe` (no console window) instead of `java.exe` (with console window) which would result in not opening a console window at all?
4. It is always helpful on running an application (or batch file) as scheduled task to be independent on the environment variables `PATHEXT` and `PATH` by specifying each application to run with full path and with file extension enclosed in double quotes.
   Using just `java` requires that Windows command processor searches in current directory and next in all directories according to `PATH` defined for the currently used account for a `java.*` file having a file extension listed in `PATHEXT` defined for the currently used account.
5. Double clicking on a batch file results in execution of the batch file by `cmd.exe` with the directory of the batch file as current directory. But running a batch file with `Run as administrator` or as scheduled task results in executing the batch file with `%SystemRoot%\System32` as current directory.
   So is it a good idea to use just `myAPP.jar` on command line without full path to this Java package with enclosing the name of the file with path in double quotes in case of a space or another character listed on last paragraph on last help page output by running in a command prompt window `cmd /?` is in file path?
   I think, this is not a good idea. I'm quite sure that `myAPP.jar` can't be found in the directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` being the current directory on running the batch file as scheduled task.

It is a common mistake made by many users that they think the environment (current directory, environment variables) on running a batch file as scheduled task is the same as on double clicking on the batch file in their user environment.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. Now I notice that, cmd is terminating if process is not taking too much time..if its take long time cmd keeps opened.Any idea on this behavior?

Comment: The command process exits when reaching end of batch file, or executing `exit`, or executing `exit /B` or `goto :EOF` outside a subroutine. If the command process remains sometimes open for a long time and sometimes not is caused by `java.exe` executing `myAPP.jar`. As long as console application `java.exe` is running, the next command line in batch file is not executed which means the batch execution is halted until `java.exe` terminates itself. So for reason why sometimes `myAPP.jar` needs a long time to finish must be searched in code of this Java application.